# Is this sentence in the Future Continuous?

Tags: grammar, tenses, future, progressive-aspect

Would be obliged if someone could clarify whether the following is in the Future Continuous tense.

> The Earth will be three degrees hotter by the year 2050.

It seems so but I need to be absolutely certain.

If it is the case, what rule would I use to describe the tense? So for Future Perfect I could say "The Future Perfect links a time in the future with a time before that". I'm looking for something along those lines if possible.

Comment: I thought Future Continuous needed a verb: '... will be <verb>ing ...'. 'Tomorrow night I will be **attending** a Michael Bolton concert.'

Comment: There are plenty of contexts where Future Continuous can validly be used with the verb ***to be***, but I don't think *"The Earth **will be being** three degrees hotter by the year 2050".* could be considered one of them. But there's nothing wrong with [The next time we see them together, she will be being led in public penance through the streets on her way to imprisonment.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she+will+be+being+led+in+public+penance+%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb (to be) in your sentence is in Simple Future (also known as Future Indefinite) tense. Some grammarians will argue that English does not have a future tense at all, but if we stick to the traditional EFL classification, will+infinitive means Simple Future. Future continuous is will+be+ing, as in

> I will be sitting on this couch the whole day tomorrow.